# How to create sphere and texturing with opengl equirectangular ios?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm new to opengl, I'm trying to create a sphere and add an eqirectangular image as texture to recreate a 3D space.

Comment: This question is way, way WAAAAY too broad. The answer to such a vague question is "by writing code." OpenGL is a big, complex framework with a very steep learning curve. I suggest finding an iOS OpenGL tutorial that walks you through the setup and creates a sphere, then modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: hank you very much follow your advice.